# why this code is not giving the correct output?

Tags: javascript

I have 81 text boxes and they contain numbers from 1 to 81, now whenever I enter two same number it should give me this message in alert box "There is a match" but it does not give this output? I dont know what is the issue? any help

```
<script>
function validateForm() {


for (var x=0; x<82; x++) {
    for (var y=x+1; y<83; y++) {

      if (document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+x].value==document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+y].value) {
        alert('There was a match');
        return false;
      }


    }


  }


alert('No matches');
  return true;
}



</script>

<form action="test.php" name="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<?php 


for ($i=0;  $i<=81; $i++)

{

?>

<input type="text" name='pk<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $i; ?>'>



<?php





}

?>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Your browser has a powerful debugger built into it that you can use to set breakpoints, inspect variables, and single-step through code to watch what's going on with it. That debugger is your best bet for figuring out these kinds of problems.

Comment: @JBux: It's comparing the `value` properties of the elements it retrieves based on `x` and `y`, not the actual values in `x` and `y`. So if `x` is `2` and `y` is `3`, and `pk2`'s value is 42 and `pk3`'s value is 42, there will be a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your web console, you'll find an error message there, telling you what's wrong.

Your inner loop uses values from `x+1` up to **and including** `82`. But you don't have a `pk82` element, your elements are `pk0` through `pk81`. So when your code gets to the end and `y` is `82`, `document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+y]` returns `undefined` and so `document.forms["myForm"]['pk'+y].value` throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Change the upper bound on your inner loop to be `< 82` rather than `< 83`. You probably also want the outer loop to end one earlier, since the last loop won't check anything.